# Optional generic parameter type narrowing

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that takes an optional argument of type `T` (a generic).

```js
function test<T>(foo?: T) {
  return foo;
}

const result = test("bar");
// result is type "bar" | undefined

const result2 = test();
// result2 is type "unknown"
```

How can I correctly type this function such that the compiler will be able to tell that the `result` variable is of type `"bar"` and not type `"bar" | undefined` and additionally the `result2` variable is of type `undefined` and not type `unknown`?

Comment: If you're sure result can never be undefined, write `const result = test("bar")!;`

Comment: Thanks! I'd like it to be inferred, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function test<T>(foo: T): T;
function test<T>(foo?: undefined): undefined;
function test<T>(foo?: T): T | undefined {
    return foo;
}

const result = test("bar"); // result is of type "bar"

const result2 = test(); //result2 is of type undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUwccAXItgJRnYDcAUKJLAsulnocQPxngAmKYDDAo%20VRP0HDR9RtHhJUGHASJwe5cdkQAfCWAFCRfRAG86iS4gBOKKCGtI19AL506EBBhvoQAGyhEAF5WDHwAIgAjAENrcIp6Dy9A2zR-KAAmYNCofASgA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use overload signatures to achieve this:

```
function test(): undefined;
function test<T>(foo: T): T;
function test<T>(foo?: T) {
  return foo;
}

const result = test("bar");
// result is type "bar"

const result2 = test();
// result2 is type undefined
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQC5HgAmKwMYKhA3AFCiSwLLpQA8AKgHybBxz5t5EbGnWjwkqDOy484Afn7ZEAb2qJEAJxRQQGpLJoBfatQgIMm9CAA2URAF4mGTACIARgEMNL7DQD0fpZoNnYwaMgAngAOKIjuXi4mZmAWWsG2AEwOTli+1AFBIVlhkTEEYMSk5ITUQA)

Comment: Perfect... other response was a few seconds before you so I gave them the check but I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is `"bar" | undefined` is because you are setting `foo` to an optional parameter. Optional parameters are the same as `undefined` in JS so using `foo?: T` will automatically append a `| undefined` to the type.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to see if I can achieve type narrowing within the function that will allow the return value to be inferred based on whether a parameter is provided or not.

Comment: @Nick Are you talking about having `undefined` as the default return value then? That can be done if you have `<T = undefined>`. I can update my answer too.